# How can I toggle a class only when a specific value in a dropdown is selected?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, toggleclass, bootstrap-select

So, I'm using the bootsrap framework, and I have a div that I want to show and hide depending on if a certain value from a dropdown list is selected.  Here's my code:

```
<label>Injury Prevention Topic</label>

<select id="InjuryPreventionTopic" class="selectpicker show-tick">
    <option value="Animal Bites">Animal Bites</option>
    <option value="Assault">Assault</option>
    <option value="Burns and Scalds">Burns and Scalds</option>
    <option value="Drowning">Drowning</option>
    <option value="falls">Falls</option>
    <option value="Firearms">Firearms</option>
    <option value="Hanging">Hanging</option>
    <option value="Homicide">Homicide</option>
    <option value="Mutilation">Mutilation</option>
    <option value="Not Further Specified">Not Further Specified</option>
    <option value="Poisoning">Poisoning</option>
    <option value="Self-Harm">Self-Harm</option>
    <option value="Sport and Leisure">Sport and Leisure</option>
    <option value="Suicide">Suicide</option>
    <option value="roadaccident">Road Traffic Accidents</option>
</select>

<div id="drop3" class="collapse">
    <label>Falls Sub Category</label>
    <select id="FallsSubCategory" class="selectpicker show-tick">
        <option>Case or Risk Identification</option>
        <option>Exercise, Strength and Balance Training</option>
        <option>Falls Risk Assessment</option>
        <option>General</option>
        <option>Hip Protectors</option>
        <option>Multifactorial Interventions</option>
        <option>Prevention Programmes</option>
        <option>Vitamin D</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $('#InjuryPreventionTopic').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'falls') {
            $('#drop3').toggleClass('in');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've tried a couple of variations, nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: code is fine see if jquery included or not

Comment: jquery is included, it's working fine on the rest of my website, just not here.  This is all inside an accordion, but that shouldn't stop it from working

Comment: check if ID of select is unique.

Comment: Yes it is, searched my entire solution to make sure

Comment: I've tested the section elsewhere just to be sure that it wasn't anything to do with the accordion affecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with my code - only where I'd put it!  I'd put it originally on the view I was working on in Visual Studio, but tried it on the _Layout page and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Instead off toggle, i think you need to add/remove your class, because if the value is not `falls` your `#drop3` element will continue with the `in` class.

```
$('#InjuryPreventionTopic').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "falls") {
        $('#drop3').addClass("in");         
    } else{
        $('#drop3').removeClass("in");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I tried that earlier, doesn't work either.  I'm thinking it's probably not the jquery that's the problem, or at least not this little snippet

Comment: this way it is working: [http://jsfiddle.net/2s4vw7ay/](http://jsfiddle.net/2s4vw7ay/)

Comment: You got some error message when rendering your html?

Comment: Ah problem solved! I moved my script to my _Layout template rather than on the view I was working on and both the toggle and add/remove methods work :)

Comment: @MichaelBale great :)

Comment: I would vote up your answer, but I don't have enough reputation at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#InjuryPreventionTopic').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'falls') {
        $('#drop3').addClass('in');         
    }
    else{
         $('#drop3').removeClass('in');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I tried that earlier, doesn't work either.  I'm thinking it's probably not the jquery that's the problem, or at least not this little snippet

Answer (score 0):

Please that you have included jquery 1.11.0 
You can check the  JsFiddle

```
Here's [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL3ouc0f/) !
```

Comment: Changing from jquery 1.10.2 to jquery 1.11.0 hasn't done anything I'm afraid, and it doesn't look like your JsFiddle example is working either sorry